# A proof for this equivalent version of the Infrared Bound/Gaussian Domination

Tags: statistical-physics, ising-model

I have recently [asked this question in Physics Stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/327434/a-proof-for-this-equivalent-version-of-the-infrared-bound-gaussian-domination), but as there was no success there, a friend pointed out that I might have a better shot here.

Consider the Ising Model in the $d$-dimensional discrete torus with side lengh $L$, denoted by  $\mathbb{T}_L $, with nearest neighbors interaction (with interaction parameter $J$, no magnetic field, and inverse of temperature $\beta$

The Gaussian Domination Bound/ Infrared Bound states that for 
every non-zero $ p \in \mathbb{T}_L^*:=(\frac{2\pi}{L} \mathbb{Z}^d) \cap (-\pi,\pi]$, we have:

$$  
\sum_{x \in \mathbb{T}_L} e^{ip \cdot x} \langle \sigma_0 \sigma_x \rangle_{L,\beta}
\le 
\frac{1}{2\beta E(p)},
$$

where $\langle \cdot \rangle^{0}_{L,\beta} $ denotes the expected value of a random variable with respect to finite volume Gibbs Measure in $\mathbb{T}_L$; $i$ is the imaginary unit; $ip \cdot x$ denotes the inner product of $ip$ and $x$; and 
$$ 
  E(p):= J \sum_{x: \|x\|_1=1} (1-e^{ip\cdot x}). 
$$

Multiple articles point out that the following statement is equivalent to that bound, $\forall (v_x) \in \mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{T}_L}$, we have
$$ 
  \sum_{x,y \in \mathbb{T}_L: \|x-y\|_1=1 }v_x \bar{v}_y
  \langle \sigma_x \sigma_y \rangle_{L,\beta} 
\le 
\frac{1}{2\beta}\sum_{x,y \in \mathbb{T}_L: \|x-y\|_1=1 } v_x \bar{v}_y G_L(x,y) + \frac{1}{L^d} \big| \sum_{x \in \mathbb{T}_L} v_x \big|^2 
\sum_{x \in \mathbb{T}_L} \langle \sigma_0 \sigma_x \rangle_{L,\beta},
$$
where 
$$
 G_L(x,y) :=  \sum_{p \in \mathbb{T}_L^* \backslash \{0\} }
\frac{1}{L^d} \frac{e^{ip \cdot (x-y)}}{E(p)}.  
$$

Well, I tried to use the usual proof as in the [Chapter 10](http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook/170220_chap_RP.pdf) of the book Statistical Mechanics of Lattice Systems:a Concrete Mathematical Introduction. Following the proof in page 465 until the moment they choose the values of $\alpha_i$, I believe that this equivalence will come choosing new values for $\alpha_i$, but to this moment, I don't know what to choose.